# Is it possible to get NHibernate to auto-generate an ID if the entity does not have one, or use the ID of the entity if it already has one?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, identity, uniqueidentifier

According to REST philosophy, a `PUT` operation should (taken from Wikipedia):

`PUT http://example.com/resources/142`

> **Update** the address member of the collection, or if it doesn't exist, **create** it.

NHibernate seems to have two ways of dealing with entity IDs:

1. Auto-generate an ID, regardless of what value the user set.
2. Use the ID assigned by the user, but lose all auto-generation capabilities.

The problem here with a `PUT` operation is the part about **creating** the entity if it doesn't exist. My assumption is that if you `PUT` a resource that doesn't exist, it will create it with the **same** ID as specified by the URL (such as 142 if we use the above example). However, NHibernate doesn't allow you to set the ID if it's auto-generated.

So my question is, is there a way to get NHibernate to auto-generate an ID if the entity doesn't have one (or has the default value for the ID type, for example 0 for ints), but also save the entity with the ID that the user set?

Answer (score 1):

Generally its a bad idea to use assigned ids.

The situation that you have is closer to the thing called [NaturalId](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/06/23/nhibernate-ltnatural-idgt.aspx). You should use it I think. You will need to have two different properties, one for databases primary key, and second as a id that is visible to users.